# Why the kernel of a holomorphic bundle homomorphism is a holomorphic vector bundle?

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles

I am having a question when learning the holomorphic vector bundles in page 67, Daniel's *Complex Geometry An Introduction*.

> Let $\phi: E\to F$ be a (holomorphic) vector bundle homomorphism. There exist
> holomorphic vector bundles $\textit{Ker}(\phi)$ and $\textit{Coker}(\phi)$ over X, such that the
> fibers over $x \in X$ are canonically isomorphic to $\textit{Ker}(\phi): E(x) \to
>  F(x)$ and $\textit{Coker}(\phi): E(x) \to
>  F(x)$, respectively.

But based on my knowledge in differential geometry, the kernel of a bundle map is not necessarily a vector bundle because the dimension of $\textit{Ker}(\phi)$ may vary on $X$. To make the kernel (or cokernel) a vector bundle, we need some conditions like $\phi$ having constant rank.

For example, let $X = \mathbb{C}$, $E = F = \mathbb{C}^2$, $\pi:E=F \to X$ be the projection to the first coordinate, and $\phi: (z,w) \mapsto (z,zw)$ be the bundle homomorphism. Then the kernel of $\phi$ is trivial on $X \setminus \{0\}$ while is $1$-dimensional at the origin.

I am wondering if I misunderstand or miss anything?

Comment: Maybe the definitions being used imply that the rank is constant?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Ah yes, the rank is required to be constant in the definition. My bad...

Comment: btw, the reason why people sometimes bake it into the definition is that the kernel being a subbundle is equivalent to the image being a subbundle, which is equivalent to rank of the bundle homomorphism being locally constant (hence constant on connected components of the base). If the kernel (or image) is a subbundle, then constancy of rank is clear; the converse is a standard theorem often proved in books.